# Question with multiple correct answers, what is it?

Tags: riddle

What question can you ask where you can get different answer every time but with all the answers being correct?

Note: can have multiple correct answers to this riddle

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. This question itself can have multiple answers. Please take a look at [tour page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a gist of the site. Thanks :)

Comment: @ABcDexter The stipulation that *every* answer is correct is quite a strong statement. Still broad, but the question itself *can* have wrong answers, so it isn’t its own answer.

Comment: @Lawrence True. That is why I commented it rather than answering.

Comment: I cannot answer this as it was put on hold, but my question would be, "What is in the universe?"

Answer (score 9):

The question would be

> What is the date and time right now?

Answer (score 8):

Another possible answer:

> How much time is left since you asked a [very broad](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) question ?

Comment: never thought I'd see roasting on PSE...

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling this is gonna be to broad, but this probably fits:

> What is the correct answer to this question?

Looking at the other answers, I suddenly came up with an additional (meta) one...

> This question (that is, the question asked by OP), which currently has 3 answers already which in my view all fit.

Answer (score 2):

You require that every answer *may* be different but every answer *must* be correct. Consider:

> What will you say next?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible, but more lateral answer:

> What is 10 + 10?

Of course it's 20..

> in base 10, but it's `10100` in base 2, `202` in base 3, `110` in base 4, `40` in base 5 etc.

Comment: Yeah, but there aren't many bases in which the answer is different, so you run out of correct answer pretty soon.